# \CUBE function from calculator package do not work with numbers greater than 25

Tags: macros, xetex, packages

i would like to use the \CUBE function from calculator package, but it does not work with numbers greater than 25

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath}
\usepackage{calculator}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\CUBE{5}{\sol}
\sol\\
\CUBE{15}{\sol2}
\sol2\\
\CUBE{25}{\sol3}
\sol3\\
\CUBE{26}{\sol4}
\sol4\\
\end{document}
```

i get the the error message:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \cctr@lengtha 
                              
l.16 \CUBE{26}{\sol4}
                     
?
```

Is there any help?

Comment: Please note that `\sol2` is no valid macro name (as well as `\sol3` and `\sol4`). Macro names can't contain numbers if LaTeX's standard category codes apply.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX3 contains a floating point library which allows much bigger numbers than `calculator`. You can use it by using `\usepackage{xfp}`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{xfp}

\newcommand\CUBE[1]{\fpeval{(#1)^3}}

\begin{document}
\CUBE{5}

\CUBE{15}

\CUBE{25}

\CUBE{35}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AAA no, calculator uses dimens for its calculations and so it can't handle large numbers. Why don't you want to use xfp?

Comment: but is there any trick to use  big numbers with calculator package ? the same error with \SQUARE function, The good thing with calculator package is, it contains many other functions which i need too

Comment: @AAA which functions do you need? `xfp` supports quite a few as well.

Comment: @AAA in [`xfp`'s documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp) there is a very brief list of functions supported inside of `\fpeval`. The syntax is mostly like what you'd use in other programming languages, so e.g. `\fpeval{sin(2*pi/3)^4-ln(2)+sqrt(6)}` should work.

Comment: mod, exp,matix and vectors operations beside calculus functions

Comment: `exp` is supported, you can get around `mod` using `\newcommand\mymod[2]{(#1)-(#2)*round((#1)/(#2))}` and then `\fpeval{\mymod{5}{2}}`. Matrix and vector operations aren't supported, only some limited support for tuples.

Comment: @AAA In that `\mymod` implemantation, the `round` is obviously wrong, that should have been `floor` so: `\newcommand\mymod[2]{(#1)-(#2)*floor((#1)/(#2))}`.

Comment: very many thanks

Comment: @AAA also this should have a set of parenthesis around it, so better would be `\newcommand\mymod[2]{((#1)-(#2)*floor((#1)/(#2)))}`.

Comment: many thanks again

Answer (score -1):

The calculator package can calculate up to 16,383.99998 (aka 2<sup>14</sup> − 2 × 10<sup>−5</sup>). So 26<sup>3</sup> > 16,383.99998, It can't calculate. Here's The cube table.

| *x* | *x*<sup>3</sup> |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1<sup>3</sup> = 1 |
| 2 | 2<sup>3</sup> = 8 |
| 3 | 3<sup>3</sup> = 27 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ |
| 24 | 24<sup>3</sup> = 13,824 |
| 25 | 25<sup>3</sup> = 15,625 |
| 26 | 26<sup>3</sup> = 17,576 |

Comment: Welcome to the TeX Stack Exchange! While you do point out the problem, you don't seem to propose a solution at the moment. Could you provide an alternative to `\CUBE` for higher numbers?